# Compilation Error with go Kit

Tags: go

I cloned a project which uses go-kit, when I try to compile the project, I get an compilation error which is something like

```
./main.go:124: cannot use makePostEndpoint(svc) (type endpoint.Endpoint) as type "github.com/go-kit/kit/transport/http".DecodeRequestFunc in argument to "github.com/go-k
it/kit/transport/http".NewServer
```

The snippet of code is as below

```
func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    svc := cayleyService{}

    postHandler := httptransport.NewServer(
        ctx,
        makePostEndpoint(svc),
        decodePostRequest,
        encodeResponse,
    )
}

func makeGetEndpoint(svc CayleyService) endpoint.Endpoint {
    return func(ctx context.Context, request interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
        req := request.(getRequest)
        v, err := svc.Get(req.Qu)
        if err != nil {
            return getResponse{v, err.Error()}, nil
        }
        return getResponse{v, ""}, nil
    }
}
```

I have version 1.8.1 of golang installed.

Comment: `httptransport.DecodeRequestFunc(makePostEndpoint(svc))`?

Comment: The error points to line 124, and there's only a couple dozen lines of code quoted. Can you at least mark which line is 124 in your sample?

Comment: httptransport.NewServer is line 124.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. There is a newer version of go kit  in which the signature of the NewServer has changed. Context has been removed and hence. I just had to remove the ctx and everything compiled.

Comment: thanks for info. helped to resolve same problem fast)